# Relation aggregate concatenate from 1 to n relation only when values are different

Tags: qgis

I have two tables linked with one to N relation

Main Table value : A

Relation Table : multiple values for value A that sometimes are identical to one another

I want to use relation_aggregate to concatenate the values of the relation table only if they are different to avoid having a result like this value 1, value 2, value 2, value 2, value 3, value 3, value 45, value 47.

I would need to have value 1, value 2, value 3, value 45, value 47 as results.

for now i have this  :

```
relation_aggregate( 
    'chrono_cer_field_3_S2_Structu_UE',
    'concatenate',
    "field_6",
    concatenator:=';'
)
```

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question to contain a question.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test fully because I don't have any relational tables to hand, but something like this should work:

```
array_to_string(                                    -- convert array to string using the ';' delimiter
    array_distinct(                                 -- get distinct values from array
        relation_aggregate(
            'chrono_cer_field_3_S2_Structu_UE',
            'array_agg',                            -- get an array of values
            "field_6"
        )
    ),
    delimiter:=';'
)
```

Comment: In fact,, my relation table is not in array format so i'm not sure this would work.

Comment: That is what the `array_agg` aggregate is for, it creates an array of values.

Comment: .Also the values in the relation table are text.

Comment: Have you tried the expression to see if it does what you want?

Comment: array_distinct syntax error :  wrong number of arguments expected 1 but received 2

Comment: Apologies, that was a typing error, I missed a closing parenthesis. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Perfect!! thank you very much this is super helpful!